# AudioPlayerAgent Streaming - Stop doesnt delete the buffer

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, audio-player, background-agents

I'm currently developing a web radio app and if the user presses the pause/stop key the stream should stop and of course when he presses play again the stream should continue.

The problem I have is, that player.Stop() only pauses the track. If you press continue again, the first 5 secounds are not read from the stream but from a buffer, then it playes no sound for a few secounds and then begins to read from the stream again.

This is fatal for a web radio app. How can I fix it? Or how can I delete the buffer?

```
    protected override void OnPlayStateChanged(BackgroundAudioPlayer player, AudioTrack track, PlayState playState)
    {
        switch (playState)
        {
            case PlayState.TrackReady:
                player.Play();
                break;
            case PlayState.Stopped:
                player.Stop();
                break;
            case PlayState.Paused:
                player.Stop();
                break; 
        }

        NotifyComplete();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allright.. just to let you guys know, this is what I did. I don't know if there's any better way but this works for me:

```
        protected override void OnPlayStateChanged(BackgroundAudioPlayer player, AudioTrack track, PlayState playState)
    {
        switch (playState)
        {
            case PlayState.Stopped:
                track.BeginEdit();
                track.Tag = track.Source.OriginalString;
                track.Source = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1", UriKind.Absolute);
                track.EndEdit();

                player.Track = track;
                break;


        protected override void OnUserAction(BackgroundAudioPlayer player, AudioTrack track, UserAction action, object param)
    {
        switch (action)
        {
            case UserAction.Play:
                if (player.PlayerState != PlayState.Playing)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        player.Play();
                    }
                    catch(Exception)
                    {
                        track.BeginEdit();
                        track.Source = new Uri(player.Track.Tag, UriKind.Absolute);
                        track.EndEdit();

                        player.Track = track;
                        player.Play();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case UserAction.Stop:
            case UserAction.Pause:
                if (player.Track.Source.OriginalString != "http://127.0.0.1/")
                {
                    player.Stop();
                }
                break;
```

Comment: +1 for posting back. This is sure to be helpful to me at some point. Favorited.

Answer (score 0):

How about ditching everything when you stop, and newing it up again when playback starts again? It seems the functionality you are using is more suited to pausing static content. Pause doesn't make much sense with radio.

Comment: As soon as you set the track or whatever to null the AudioPlayerAgent closes itself. And because this is a backgroundtask, which also runs when the app is closed, I cant restart it.

Comment: Ouch. I'll be following this with interest as we'll probably be writing the same in few months.